# Rails accessing custom method instance variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, controller

What I am trying to do is add a simple search to a 'show' view in my rails app. I've watched the rails cast about simple search and it's given me some good direction but I can't seem to get it to work with my situation. I just have a list of FAQs and want to have a search filter for the 'question(s)'.

Here's my views/guests/show.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag faq_search_guests_path, method: :get, remote: true, :id => "faq_search_form"     do %>
<p>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>

<div id="faq-search-test"></div>

<% @faqs.each do |f| %>

<h4>Question</h4>
<%= f.question %>

<h4>Answer</h4>
<%= f.answer %>

<% end %>
```

Here's the controller/guests_controller.rb method that originally sets @faqs

```
def show
@guest = Guest.find(params[:id])
@hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
@faqs = Faq.where(hotel_id: @hotel.id)
@template = Template.where( hotel: @hotel.id )
@visit = Visit.where("hotel_id = ? AND guest_id = ?", @hotel.id, @guest.id).last
@visit = Visit.find(params[:visit_id]) if params[:visit_id] && (@visit.hotel_id == @hotel.id)
unless current_user.hotels.include?(@hotel)
  render :file => "public/401.html", :status => :unauthorized
end
```

end

Here's my controllers/guests_controller.rb custom method my form is calling

```
 def faq_search
  @faq_result = Faq.search(params[:search])
  render :nothing => true
 end
```

Here's my routes.rb for that

```
resources :guests do
  get 'faq_search', :on => :collection
end
resources :faqs
```

Here's my models/faq.rb

```
def self.search(search)
if search
  where('question LIKE ?', '%#{search}%')
else
  scoped
end
end
```

So from here, I am having trouble displaying @faq_result in show.html.erb. I guess I have no idea how to access an instance variable from a custom controller method from a view.

Any help would be much appreiciated :)!

Comment: Which part is not working? any error? can you access `yourapp/guests/faq_search`? AND `render nothing: true`, well, will render noting.

Comment: In the same view I had <% if faq_result %><%= faq_result %><% end %> (there are 'at' signs before those) just to see if I can pull in the variable and display it. That did not work. Nothing displayed.

Comment: Try to change `render nothing: true` to `render json: { result: @faq_result.to_json }` or create serializer for Faq.